# PulseAudio won't remember USB dock default output

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

Tried `pactl set-card-profile <symbolic-name> <profilename>` and even added it to `/etc/pulse/default.pa` but that only works on initial boot when my USB dock is already plugged in. If it wasn't plugged in on boot or I unplug and replug, the default output device goes back to headphones again rather than line out.

I suspect I have to change the profile in `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets` but it seems nothing I do effects anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out! I simply created a udev rule to switch sink when usb dock connects. I referenced the post to help make the script: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/1afh8s/frustration_with_pulseaudio_and_udev_rules/